# When network provisioning happens through a hotspot (for a headless device), how can I notify the user of a failure when switching to station mode?

Tags: networking, wifi, communication

When a user connects to the hotspot of a headless device for configuring Wi-Fi credentials for device provisioning and if it fails to connect to Wi-Fi once Wi-Fi credentials are saved, the user doesn't get a notification for error happened as they are no longer connected to the hotspot and the device is not in station mode.

After some time, when hotspot mode appears again, they have to open or refresh the page to configure Wi-Fi again.

With the above context, is there any way we can send a failure notification to the hotspot page in real time if the Wi-Fi module fails to switch to station mode?

Answer (score 3):

You're posing this question at the wrong level. You need to think about the whole process - starting with whatever initiated the original connection to the headless device. This will either have been an app, in which case you can manage the process through the app, or a written instruction set.

Based on how you decide to architect the process, you might need to re-assess the physical aspects of the user interface on your headless device. Maybe a status indicator or audio prompts, maybe some buttons. Also consider how to recover cleanly if the process is interrupted at any stage.

At the level of a WiFi connection, no it is not possible for a hotspot to force a client to connect to it.